# Проверка ввода на латиницу

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать проверку на латиницу на чистом js(чтобы можно было вводить только латинские буквы)

Comment: например так `/^[a-z]*$/i`

Comment: а это разве на чистом? можете прокомментровать, если не затруднит?

Comment: чистее не бывает :) [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: а есть способы "попроще"?)

Answer (score 1):

ну есть как варинат по коду сравнить у символов есть коды и сранвить по ним что типа таекова

```
window.onload = () => {
        var T = document.getElementById('cli');
        var B = 'A'.charCodeAt(0);
        var E = 'Z'.charCodeAt(0);
        T.onkeyup = (e) => {
            for (let i = B; i != E; i++) {

                var C = event.target.value;
                for (let j = 0; j < C.length; j++) {
                    if (C[j].charCodeAt(0) < i || C[j].charCodeAt(0) > i) {
                        C.replace(C[j], '');
                        console.log(`Current: ${C[j].charCodeAt(0)} - Target: ${i} J: - ${j}`);
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

вот так вот и не какова js

```
<form action="">
        <input type="text"  id="cli" pattern="[A-Za-z]">
        <button type="submit">send</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: здесь события, слишком сложно для моего уровня. Мне нужен обычный вариант..есть два инпута и кнопка. В первом инпуте логин, во втором пароль. нужно сделать, чтобы при воде нелатинских символов всплывал алерт "правильно или "неправильно" через if else. Все это должно срабатывать при онклике на кнопку

Comment: обновил ответ ук

Comment: @РомаПрокопец, без событий невозможно показывать alert

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно.

```js
$('form').on('keydown',(e) => {
    var regExp = '^[a-zA-Z]+$';
    e.target.value.search(regExp) == false ? '' : $(e.target).val($(e.target).val().substr(0,$(e.target).val().length-1))
}).on('keyup',(e) => {
    var regExp = '^[a-zA-Z]+$';
    e.target.value.search(regExp) == false ? '' : $(e.target).val($(e.target).val().substr(0,$(e.target).val().length-1))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```